# Users relationships with other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

I'm trying create a model that is a parent to other users.
Here is what I have right now:

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 .
 .
 .
  has_one :guardian_of_child
end


class GuardianOfChild < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "guardian_id"
  has_many :users, foreign_key: "child_id"

end
```

Migration:

```
class CreateGuardianOfChildren < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :guardian_of_children do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to access 'guardian_id' or 'child_id'

```
<% @guardian_of_children.each do |guardian_of_child| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= guardian_of_child.user.guardian_id %></td>
```

it gives me this error:

```
undefined method `guardian_id' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong? Could somebody help me out?

Comment: Could you clarify the relationship you are trying to model? It's not clear from the association you declare. For example the has_many relationship should have a belongs to on the other side.
Furthermore, you'd be good to debug what is nil. for example leave of guardian_id and see if any user at all is displayed

Comment: Can you provide a structure.sql or schema.rb please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. Basically a parent to child relationship model.

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :guardian_of_children, foreign_key: "guardian_id"
    has_many :child_of_guardians, class_name: "GuardianOfChild", foreign_key: "child_id"

  end

  class GuardianOfChild < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :guardian, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'guardian_id'
    belongs_to :child, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'child_id'

  end
```